# dynamic loading of python module across namespaces

Tags: python, module

My dir structure is

```
solution
- classes
  - setup.py
  - parser.py
- driver.py
```

Contents of setup.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from importlib import import_module
import subprocess
import sys
import imp
import os

class Setup(object):
    def __init__(self,packages=["yaml", "jinja2", "cryptography"], *args):
        self.packages = packages
        if len(args) > 0:
            self.packages.extend(args)
        print(self.packages)

    def _install(self,package):
        subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])

    def _global_imports(self, modulename, shortname=None, asfunction=False):
        print("Module being imported is {}".format(modulename))
        if shortname is None:
            shortname = modulename
        if asfunction is False:
            globals()[shortname] = import_module(modulename)
        else:        
            globals()[shortname] = eval(modulename + "." + shortname)

    def import_packages(self):
        for item in self.packages:
            try:
                imp.find_module(item)
                found = True
            except ImportError as e:
                found = False
                self._install(item)

            self._global_imports(item)
```

COntents of parser.py

```
import os
import copy
from classes.certgen import *
from classes.setup import *

s = Setup()
s.import_packages()

class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, templatefile, paramsfile):
        assert os.path.isfile(templatefile), "Template file not provided/does not exist"
        self.templatefile = templatefile
        assert os.path.isfile(paramsfile), "Parameter file not provided/does not exist"
        self.paramsfile = paramsfile

    def load_paramsfile(self):
        paramsdict = None
        with open(self.paramsfile, 'r') as stream:
            try:
                paramsdict = yaml.load(stream)
                print(params)
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print(exc)

        return paramsdict
```

Contents of driver.py

```
from classes.parser import *
import sys

template="../sometemplate.j2"
params="../parameters.yaml"

p = Parser(template,params)

r = p.load_paramsfile()
```

When i execute the driver code, I get following err:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = p.load_paramsfile()
  File "/home/new/solution/classes/parser.py", line 22, in load_paramsfile
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
NameError: global name 'yaml' is not defined
```

My understanding is that when I add to globals in setup.py, it would be available in parser.py ... I see that my understanding maybe off in that globals are scoped by namespace. So how can I achieve using a class like setup.py to dynamically import modules that would be required per namespace?

Appreciate any pointers/help in this regard

Comment: what on earth are you trying to do with this overcomplicated mess??? Just import what you need in each module (and for God's sake do NOT use star imports).

Comment: im trying to create a module that can be used by others in the org for two purposes 1) check needed modules and install them if not available and 2) import them .... the star imports is used just for testing purposes .. i wont pollute .... hope this gives context to why im doing this ....

Comment: Have you looked at existing packaging solutions?